# JSON response is appended to HTML template output

Tags: go, go-gin

I have this weird behavior which I think is caused by using conflicting infrastructures:

1. Traefik for reverse proxy
2. In-house library, SM, which wraps all requests into our back-end language; It parses JSON from request and return a certain JSON structure for the response
3. For Traefik, I must return a HTML page rather than a JSON.

I use Go for BE and render HTML templates for FE

My flow look kinda like this:

```
func (r RestrictedHandler) Exec(c *smContext) (interface{}, ServiceError) {
    // check if we have a cookie for auth
    if tokenCookie, err := tokens.GetTokenFromCookie(c); err != nil {
        c.HTML(401, "login.html")
        return "", err
    } else {
        return r, nil
    }
}
```

And the wrapper for this:

```
    if response, err := newH1.Exec(hc); err != nil {
        c.JSON(err.GetStatusCode(), gin.H{
            "status": "error",
            "error": err
        })
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "status": "success",
            "data": response
        })
    }
```

So what happens here (I suspect) is that I "push" into the response "buffer" both HTML text and JSON text, resulting in the following html page the user gets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    My returned page
   </body>
</html>{"status":"error","error":{"msg":"Unauthorized error","type":"Unauthorized"}}
```

So my questions is, how to stop writing into the context after **c.HTML()**?

1. I tried c.Next() and c.Abort(), but I guess they are more for chaining middleware.
2. Changing the SM library code (shared code with people I work with, but still possible to submit a pull request), to somehow check, "if response has html tags in it, don't do c.JSON()".

Comment: You can try to read content type of the response if not `'application/json'` than don't add JSON values. `c.Writer.Header().Get("Content-Type")` is how you read content type. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

So I talked with the guy who was in charge of our SM library. We added a flag to the *context* object, called "responseOverridden". Anyone with the reference to the context object can set the flag (in his own service), and then in the SM library we just don't return a JSON if this flag is set:

```
// someService.go
func (r RestrictedHandler) Exec(c *smContext) (interface{}, ServiceError) {
// check if we have a cookie for auth
if tokenCookie, err := tokens.GetTokenFromCookie(c); err != nil {
    c.HTML(401, "login.html")
    c.replyOverriden = true
    return "", err
} else {
    return r, nil
}
```

}

in library code:

```
 // SM.go
 response, err := newH1.Exec(hc);
 if !hc.responseOverridden {
     err != nil {
        c.JSON(err.GetStatusCode(), gin.H{
          "status": "error",
          "error": err
        })
     } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
          "status": "success",
          "data": response
        })
     }
 } 
 // someone probably handled something in hc, so don't return JSON
```